# SQL - Each column show results from a specific range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I am trying to create a sales matrix inside of SAP.

The SQL report I want to run is very basic. It involves the following:

```
SELECT 
    T1.ItemCode, SUM(T1.Quantity)
FROM
    OINV T0
INNER JOIN
    INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE
    ItemCode IS NOT NULL
    AND CardCode = 'C001500'
GROUP BY 
    T1.ItemCode
ORDER BY 
    T1.ItemCode
```

I want the `SUM(t1.quantity)` field to be broken down into weeks but can't quite figure out how to split this down.

I want `Current Week` which will be a `daterange` between `Getdate()` and `Getdate()+7`, Then `Week1` which will be `Getdate()+8 To`GetDate()+14` etc... This will carry on for 12 weeks.

Thanks for any help!

Andy

Comment: I am using SAP B1 and will be using an addon called B1up inside of SAP to handle this query... 
I am writing the code inside MS SQL server management studio 17.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `WEEK()` function in HAHA SQL (which I assume you are using with SAP).  Adding an additional `GROUP BY` on that calculated value should do the trick.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/20f5758b7519101498b28e41757fe664.html

If you are using mySAP then it is SQL Server and `DATEPART` is what you want.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

I have written this piece of code now, however the SUM T1.Quantity isn't totaling. I am seeing AHV16 selling 1 item in week 5, then another instance AHV16 selling one item in week 2. and AHV 16 showing NULL for week 1 - 12, and showing 1 for 12 week total (Swhich should be Week 2 + Week 5.

```
SELECT T1.ItemCode
, '12 Week Total' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-84,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,0,Getdate())))
, 'Current Week' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-7,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,0,Getdate())))
, 'Week 2' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-14,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-8,Getdate())))
, 'Week 3' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-21,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-15,Getdate())))
, 'Week 4' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-28,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-22,Getdate())))
, 'Week 5' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-35,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-29,Getdate())))
, 'Week 6' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-42,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-36,Getdate())))
, 'Week 7' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-49,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-43,Getdate())))
, 'Week 8' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-56,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-50,Getdate())))
, 'Week 9' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-63,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-57,Getdate())))
, 'Week 10' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-70,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-64,Getdate())))
, 'Week 11' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-77,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-71,Getdate())))
, 'Week 12' = (SELECT sum(T1.Quantity) WHERE (T0.DocDate>=DateAdd(Day,-84,Getdate()) AND T0.DocDate<=DateAdd(D,-78,Getdate())))


    FROM OINV T0 INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry

WHERE ItemCode IS NOT NULL and CardCode = 'C001500'
GROUP BY T1.ItemCode, T0.Docdate

Order By T1.ItemCode
```

Comment: Tips: You don't mention the datatype of `DocDate`, but if it is a `DateTime` then you may have issues with the time-of-day. I suggest using `declare @Today as DateTime = Cast( GetDate() as Date );` to get the current date at midnight and using that value throughout. Rather than the flurry of `select`s you might want to try `Sum( case when DateAdd( day, -14, @Today ) <= T0.DocDate and T0.DocDate < DateAdd( day, -7, @Today ) then T1.Quantity end )`. That will conditionally sum the values with the rest defaulting to NULL. Note the use of a half-open interval with `<=` and `<`.